# What's a good cctv app to start out on? Zoneminder or Motion?

Tags: video, webcam

I've been asked to put together a cctv solution for a small business. Ubuntu is my choice OS, and I'm looking at Zoneminder or Motion as the app of choice. Any experience with one or the other? Also, any recommendations on cameras? I'm thinking we'll try a stock usb webcam to begin with, but I have no experience in this area. The store area is about 25 feet long, 10 feet wide, with large west-facing windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good success with Motion and the logitech webcam pro 9000.

One note of caution, in the motion package that is in the repositories for 9.10 I had to add the following lines to the init.d script.

mkdir -p /var/run/motion
chown motion:motion /var/run/motion

after the DEFAULTS entry.

Other than that, works pretty well. It outputs whatever the camera is seeing to a web port so you can monitor it from either your network or via ssh tunnel. The config file is pretty simple too. It outputs to both still images and creates flv files which are better for reviewing several hours of motion capture quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking Motion's modularity might give me a little more flexibility.